# gmake: *** No rule to make target (install cmake on gitbash, do not have makefile)

Tags: c++11, makefile, cmake, shiny

I d like to install cmake on gitbash (Windows 10) , because I need it o run shiny-server.
https://github.com/rstudio/shiny-server/wiki/Building-Shiny-Server-from-Source#what-if-a-sufficiently-recent-version-of-cmake-isnt-available

When I run ./configure ,  it gives me the following error

```
*CMake 3.15.2, Copyright 2000-2019 Kitware, Inc. and Contributors
C compiler on this system is: tcc
C++ compiler on this system is: C:\MinGW\bin\g++.exe C:\MinGW\bin\g++.exe
Makefile processor on this system is: gmake
C:\MinGW\bin\g++.exe has setenv
C:\MinGW\bin\g++.exe has unsetenv
C:\MinGW\bin\g++.exe has environ in stdlib.h
C:\MinGW\bin\g++.exe has stl wstring
C:\MinGW\bin\g++.exe has <ext/stdio_filebuf.h>
---------------------------------------------
gmake: *** No rule to make target '/c/Users/../cmake-3.15.2/Source/cmAddCustomCommandCommand.cxx', neededby 'cmAddCustomCommandCommand.o'.  Stop.
---------------------------------------------
Error when bootstrapping CMake:
Problem while running gmake*
```

I know that the problem originates because I do not have makefile,  however gnumake-windows do not possess makefile.

Could you please tell me how I can overcome this issue,  or how I can install cmake on windows ,  or how I can run shiny-server on windows ?

With lots of thanks

Comment: Why are you building CMake from source? There are installable packages you can [download](https://cmake.org/download/) for Windows.

Comment: Also when I d like to install make-4.2.1 , which has makefile.com, and run ./configure;  it gives me the following error.  I assume that I can not install this on Windows   $ ./configure
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/c/Users/.../make-4.2.1':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details

Comment: If you want to build GNU make on Windows please read the `README.W32` file that comes with GNU make.