# "No rule to maketarget" when installing CMake through command line

Tags: c++, cmake, git-bash

As I stated, I am attempting to install CMake through Git Bash on Windows. Upon running the following command: `./bootstrap --qt-gui` I get about 30 seconds of loading before an error is thrown. Here is the log in Bash:

```
CMake 3.17.2, Copyright 2000-2020 Kitware, Inc. and Contributors
Found GNU toolchain
C compiler on this system is: gcc
C++ compiler on this system is: g++
Makefile processor on this system is: make
g++ has setenv
g++ has unsetenv
g++ has environ in stdlib.h
g++ has stl wstring
g++ has <ext/stdio_filebuf.h>
---------------------------------------------
make: *** No rule to make target '/c/Users/jaken/Desktop/Files/CMake/cmake-3.17.2/Source/cmAddCustomCommandCommand.cxx', needed by 'cmAddCustomCommandCommand.o'.  Stop.
---------------------------------------------
Error when bootstrapping CMake:
Problem while running make
---------------------------------------------
Log of errors: /c/Users/jaken/Desktop/Files/CMake/cmake-3.17.2/Bootstrap.cmk/cmake_bootstrap.log
---------------------------------------------
```

I have the log available but it's rather long and I'm not sure what part would be relevant. However, the mentioned file *definitely exists* in the target directory, so I'm not sure what the issue is. This is a brand new download of CMake so unless that is broken the file should be fine.

Does anyone know a possible solution to this issue? It's not particularly time sensitive but I am hoping to learn OpenGL and this is a first step I need to take (as far as I know).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! There is already a very similar question about this topic on the site [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58165477/gmake-no-rule-to-make-target-install-cmake-on-gitbash-do-not-have-makefil). Building in Git Bash is not officially supported by CMake on their [site](https://cmake.org/install/). I encourage you to read through their instructions for installing on Windows. Why not just install CMake from the pre-compiled binaries provided on the CMake site?

Comment: I've done so. Was hoping to learn a bit more about command line usage but I might save that for something a bit less... big. Thank you.